# Yodlee: Transaction types

Tags: yodlee

In the sample json response for executeUserSearchRequest api there is transaction type "deposit":
"transactionType":"deposit",
"transactionTypeId":82,

API Url:
https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/executeUserSearchRequest

In documentation I can find a list of possible values of TransactionBaseType.
Is there a similar list for transaction types?

Answer (score 0):

The list of transaction types are not available on the online documentation. I will give this as a feedback internally to get this list online.

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee has defined the following transaction types too.

https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/Transaction_Categorization